# Select columns from several tables with count

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have 3 tables in SQL Server:

- Sales (customerId)
- Customer (customerId, personId)
- Person (personId, firstName, lastName)

and I need to return the top 10 customers.

I used this query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 
    CustomerID, COUNT(CustomerID)
FROM
    Sales
GROUP BY
    (CustomerID)
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(CustomerID) DESC
```

The query currently returns only the `customerId` and count, but I also need to return the `firstName` and `lastName` of these customers from the `Person` table.

I know I need to reach the `firstName` and `lastName` by correlating between `Sales.customerId` and `Customer.customerId`, and from `Customer.personId` to get the `Person.personId`.

My question is whether I need to use an inner join or union, and how to use either of them to get the `firstName` and `lastName` of these customers

Comment: Join this query with a sub query which returns person’s name.

Comment: A simple `JOIN` seems like all your need, assuming that the relation from `Sales` to `Customer` many to 1 and `Customer` to `Person` is 1 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union is mostly used for disjoint sets. To achieve your target, u can go with inner-join.

If you want to use joins, then here is the query which works similarly to your requirement.

```
SELECT TOP 10 S.CustomerID, P.FirstName,P.LastName, count(*) 
FROM Sales S 
   INNER JOIN Customer C on S.CustomerId=C.CustomerId
   INNER JOIN Person P on C.PersonId = P.PersonId
GROUP BY (S.CustomerID, P.FirstName,P.LastName) 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `inner join` like this :

```
SELECT TOP 10   S.CustomerID
              , P.FirstName
              , P.LastName
              , COUNT (1) AS CountOfCustomer -- this is equal count(*)
  FROM  Sales S
        INNER JOIN Customer C ON S.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
        INNER JOIN Person P ON C.PersonId = P.PersonId
 GROUP BY S.CustomerID, P.FirstName, P.LastName
 ORDER BY 4 DESC; -- this is equal order by count(*)
```